# Add a column in my query that will have the number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Dears,

i have the below query,

```html
select comp_code,branch_code,deal_no,LENGTH(deal_no)len_,start_date,num_of_skip_install,UPFRONT_PROFIT_Y_N,after_Status,product_class FROM AIBB_TEMP_SKIP_TABLE where comp_code = 1 and branch_code = 1010 order by comp_code,branch_code,len_ ,deal_no;
```

I would like to add a new column that will have the number of rows. For example if the query will return 28 results, i want the new column to display 28 in all the rows

Answer (score 4):

You can use the analytical function `count` as follows:

```
count(1) over () as total_rows --add this into the select list in your query
```

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT COMP_CODE,
       BRANCH_CODE,
       DEAL_NO,
       LENGTH(DEAL_NO) LEN_,
       START_DATE,
       NUM_OF_SKIP_INSTALL,
       UPFRONT_PROFIT_Y_N,
       AFTER_STATUS,
       PRODUCT_CLASS,
       COUNT(1) OVER () AS TOTAL_ROWS -- <-- ADDED THIS  
  FROM AIBB_TEMP_SKIP_TABLE
 WHERE COMP_CODE = 1
   AND BRANCH_CODE = 1010
 ORDER BY COMP_CODE,
          BRANCH_CODE,
          LEN_,
          DEAL_NO;
```